# jquery - AnimatedModal, get data-* of clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using AnimatedModal on my website and it works great but now I need to get data attribute of clicked element so I do:

```
$(".wanted-modal").animatedModal({
    modalTarget: "wanted",
    color: "#3e94ec",
    beforeOpen: function( event ) {
        console.log( $(this).data('test') );
    }
});
```

but I'm getting `undefined`, why?

HTML:

```
<a href="#wanted" data-test="1" class="button-standard wanted-modal">Click me</a>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like for that element with `data-test`? Also are you sure that `$(this)` is the correct element being targeted? What does `event.target` within `beforeOpen()` come back as?

Comment: `undefined` implies that the HTML element in question doesn't have the `data-test` attribute. It's quite possible that `this` isn't referencing the element you think it is. We need to see the HTML element.

Comment: I added HTML into question.

Comment: Yeah @ScottMarcus is most likely right, `$(this)` is not the `<a>` element. It's likely the modal or something else. Try seeing if `event.target` returns the `<a>` element with `data-test`.

Comment: I believe the issue is that the `.animatedModal()` call must be binding `this` to a different object than the link, because when I do a test with a simple `click` event handler, your code works. Add a `console.log(this);` to your `beforeOpen` callback to see what object `this` is binding to.

Comment: So is it possible to pass this data into this beforeOpen?

Comment: The element won't get passed to the function; that's not the implementation of the library. You'll just have to lookup the element yourself: `$('.wanted-modal').data('test');`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it might be bit too late, but will be helpful for some other, There is a workaround, inside animatgedModel.js add variabel (ex: var currentActive = null) after settings.

there is a function named **model.click**, add this

```
currentActive = $(this);
currentActive.addClass("popup-active");
```

and also there is another function **closeBt.click**, add this

```
currentActive.removeClass("popup-active");
currentActive = null;
```

finally on **beforeOpen** you can select the element which was clicked